# What are the points called in a dataset where the points have the same features but different labels

Tags: terminology

What are the points called in a dataset where the points have the same features but different labels?

For example, I am trying to predict whether some object is a hot dog. But I only have access to features `is_wrapped_in_bread` and `has_meat_in_the_middle`.

```
| object        | is_wrapped_in_bread | has_meat_in_the_middle | is_hotdog |
| salad         | false               | false                  | false     |
| hotdog        | true                | true                   | true      |
| burger        | true                | true                   | false     |
| veggie burger | true                | false                  | false     |
```

In the example above, `burger` and `hotdog` are not distinguishable based on the available features. Is there a name for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any specific term for this but in general I would call this either:

- **noisy data**, typically in the case where these inconsistencies are due to mistakes in the annotation process (normally the proportion of mistakes is much lower than the proportion of correct instances).
- **poor data design**, if the way instances/features are defined doesn't match the goal of the ML process (the example provided would fall into this category).

Comment: Right, but I want a general term that captures both the notion of potentially bad labels, and potentially bad features. Is there such a term?

Comment: if there is I don't know it. let's see if somebody else has one